# How can I integrate Twilio Video into my asp.net mvc application using plain javascript?

Tags: twilio-video

The problem is that, I have already build an mvc application with Twilit Chat. Twilio Chat sample code is in plain javascript. But Twilio Video sample code provided by Twilio is in React (Node js application). How can i get simple javasript to add twilio video featuer into my existing application?

Answer (score 1):

If you now the plain JS than you can convert that example. Just load the Twilio Js file first after loading that file, load your Js files. i.e.

```
 <script src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.7.2/twilio-video.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/js/twiliojs/meeting.js"></script>
```

replace meeting.js file with your actual file in which you write code for connecting to twilio. Best way is to generate Token via Rest API.